# Is it possible to "adopt" a class as a child?

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, extends

I'm currently writing a class, that should serve as an add-on to already existing classes. For example, let my add-on class be the following:

```java
public class NewClass {}
```

Also, assume there already exist classes like:

```java
public final class ExistingClassA {}
public final class ExistingClassB {}
...
```

These I am not allowed to change.
For some algorithms, I'd like to define the existing classes to be children of my `NewClass`, though. So instead of inherit from some class with `extends`, I kind of want to achieve the opposite: I want to "adopt" a class, as if the existing classes were originally defined this way:

```java
public final class ExistingClassA extends NewClass {}
public final class ExistingClassB extends NewClass {}
...
```

Is this even possible in Java? And if so, is it also possible to add a class as a parent of a class, which already extends another class?

**Edit:**

To make my situation a bit clearer, I'll try describing what I want to achieve in more detail. E.g. assume a variable `myVar`, which should only be instance of specific classes. If those classes belonged to a common parent class, this wouldn't be a problem:

```java
public final class ExistingClassA extends CommonParentClass {}
public final class ExisitingClassB extends CommonParentClass {}
public final class ExistingClassC extends CommonParentClass {}

...
/* We're inside some class now... */
CommonParentClass myVar; // May be of ExistingClassA, ExistingClassB, or ExistingClassC.
```

Now say, I want `myVar` to be only of the class `ExistingClassA` or `ExistingClassB`. Assuming I could "adopt" those two classes with my `NewClass`, I could also just write:

```java
NewClass myVar; // May be of ExistingClassA, or ExistingClassB, but not ExistingClassC.
```

Since this seems *not* to be possible (from reading the comments), what approach would be the smartest to achieve the goal of just allowing `myVar` so be of a subset of `CommonParentClass`?

Comment: There's no mechanism in Java to do this unless you resort to highly complex manipulations using reflection.  One simple way to do this is to create a proxy that exposes the functions of both the existing and new classes.

Comment: Interesting. With which languages is this possible?

Comment: I'm curious what this is for? It feels like a case of you developing a solution in your head and asking about how to implement that solution rather than asking about the question.

Comment: @JimGarrison Sounds interesting! Can you explain that a bit more or provide links for further reading?

Comment: @MatthewKerian I added some further explanation to what I'm aiming for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no compile-time mechanism to check whether a class extends either class A or B. If the authors of `A` and `B` did not define that they are related, they are not.

You have several options:

- You could use instanceof and then cast to the specified type.

  ```java
  Object myObj = ...;
  if (myObj instanceof Alpha) {
      ((Alpha) myObj).doSomething();
  }
  else if (myObj instanceof Bravo) {
      ((Bravo) myObj).doSomethingElse();
  }
  else {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("myObj" must be of either Alpha or Bravo");
  }
  ```
- Or you could make a wrapper object accepting either in the constructor:

  ```java
  class Either<A, B> {
      A a;
      B b;
      boolean isA;
      Either(A a) {
          this.a = a;
          this.isA = true;
      }
      Either(B b) {
          this.b = b;
      }
      boolean isA() {
          return isA;
      }
      A getA() {
          return a;
      }
      B getB() {
          return b;
      }
  }
  ```

  and then call it:

  ```
  Either<Alpha, Bravo> either = new Either(...);
  if (either.isA()) {
      either.getA().doSomething();
  }
  else {
      either.getB().doSomethingElse();
  }
  ```

---

But I fail to see *how* you want to use those two classes. Do they have a method with the same name? And why don't you just simply use two variables?